# End of File Exception on ObjectInputStream.readObject

Tags: java, file, eofexception

My application streams twitter data and writes them to files.

```
while(true){
        Status status = queue.poll();

        if (status == null) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

        if(status!=null){
            list.add(status);
        }

        if(list.size()==10){
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            ObjectOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                String filename = "C:/path/"+topic+"-"+uuid+".ser";
                fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                out.writeObject(list);
                tweetsDownloaded += list.size();
                if(tweetsDownloaded % 100==0)
                    System.out.println(tweetsDownloaded+" tweets downloaded");
            //  System.out.println("File: "+filename+" written.");
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            list.clear();
    }
```

I have this code which gets data from files.

```
while(true){
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();

    if(files != null){
        Arrays.sort(//sorting...);

        //Here we manage each single file, from data-load until the deletion
        for(int i = 0; i<files.length; i++){
            loadTweets(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
            //TODO manageStatuses
            files[i].delete();
            statusList.clear();
        }

    }

}
```

The method loadTweets() does the following operations:

```
private static void loadTweets(String filename) {

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        statusList = (List<Status>) in.readObject();
        in.close();
    }
    catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know why sometimes it throws a

> EOFException

when running this line

```
statusList = (List<Status>) in.readObject();
```

Anybody knows how I can solve this? Thank you.

Comment: `EOFException` suggests that there is no more data to read. Based on your code it looks like it happens at start of the file, which means it is empty. Why it is empty at the point of reading? Possibly because you didn't add anything to it yet (different thread erased its data, and before managed to add new one your thread attempted to read file content). It is hard to tell without having [mcve].

Comment: @Pshemo The file is not empty, in fact its length is greater than zero when this happens. How could I handle this?

Comment: Edit your question and show the code which was used to write those files.

Comment: @VGR I've done it, please check it

Comment: Have you taken any steps to ensure that your file reading code does not execute at the same time your other code is writing the same file?

Comment: @VGR As far as I know the file is available to the read whenever its write has ended. Isn't that true? If so, how can I prevent this?

Comment: "*As far as I know the file is available to the read whenever its write has ended*" that may be true, if you are in the middle of writing to file then others can't read from it, but that is not the case here. Your file is being "reset" by `new FileOutputStream(filename);`. After that it doesn't have any content, but before you execute `out.writeObject(list);` which *may* lock the file (depending on buffering) there is some time period where file is not being used but is empty which seems to be causing your problem. This looks like classic readers-writers problem. You need synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what was necessary to solve this. Thanks to @VGR's comment, I thought to pause the executing thread for 0.2 seconds if the file has been created less than a second ago.

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis()-files[i].lastModified()<1000){
        Thread.sleep(200);
```

This prevents the exception and the application works now fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen that you're passing the file correctly with the getAbsolutePath() based on a previous question of yours

From what I've read that can be a couple of things, one of them the file being null.

Explaining this idea, you might have written the file but something caused the file to have nothing inside, this might cause an EOFException. The file in fact exists it's just empty

**EDIT**

Try to enclose the code in `while(in.available() > 0)`

It would look like this

```
private static void loadTweets(String filename) {

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        while(in.available() > 0) {
            statusList = (List<Status>) in.readObject();
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you would suggest me to ignore the file and simply go on?

Comment: Handle the error and keep going, just knowing that you have nothing on that file so the status list will be in fact null

Comment: Thank you, I'll follow your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately this keeps throwing the error and I verified that the file was not null, by printing File.length. The error it prompts are "peekByte" and "readFully". Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: Hum... can you print the stack trace

Comment: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at utilities.FileReader.loadTweets(FileReader.java:61)
        at utilities.FileReader.main(FileReader.java:34)

Comment: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at utilities.FileReader.loadTweets(FileReader.java:59)
        at utilities.FileReader.main(FileReader.java:34)

Comment: try to enclose the code inside this `while(in.available() > 0)`

Comment: Recheck the answer I made an edit on code that you must enclosure the while was starting in the wrong place

Comment: It doesn't work, it throws a NullPointerException when using statusList

Comment: I only now noticed, you did not closed the FileOutputStream when you where writing the file. Ensure that you close always the FileStreams and ObjectStreams in this case, when you're writing you close the ObjectStream with out.close(), as you did, and then fos.close(). This is a shot in the dark but that might be the problem. Also when reading, after closing the ObjectStream in.close() close the FileStream fis.close() let's see if this helps

Comment: Nothing changed. In fact the exception is thrown before closing the input stream. I don't really know how to solve this.

Comment: Another shot in the dark.... Right before the while add this line `statusList = new ArrayList<Status>();` basically initialize the statusList

Comment: Nope neither this time it works. Thanks for your effort, any further help will be much appreciated